# Why doesn't my SKAction run properly?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So i have this problem where my SKAction dosen't run properly. Sometimes it runs by duration of 0.2 but most of the times it is instant no animation of the node moving to its position.

```
array_dot[j].runAction(SKAction.moveToY(premakni_do, duration: 0.2))
```

More code where this is used. This is the function to move the Sphere Nodes to one place down if the place is free underneath them (idk if this code is good but it works kinda :P). Also 152 on Y is the max as low as they can go.

What i do is run through all the nodes that match the names then move them to an array, reverse that array and then move them as low as they can go. But as mentioned before the moving of the Nodes works, but most of the times (90%) the animation doesn't run. Also i am not using any of the physics.

```
func premakni_pike()
{
    array_dot.removeAll()
    var preveri_pozicija: CGFloat = 0
    self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("//*")
        {
            node, stop in
            if(node.name == "blue" || node.name == "yellow" || node.name == "red" || node.name == "green")
            {
                self.array_dot.append(node)
            }

        }
    let velikost_array = array_dot.count
    array_dot = array_dot.reverse()
    var premakni_do: CGFloat = 0

    for j in 0...velikost_array-1
    {
        if(array_dot[j].position.y != 156)
        {
            premakni_do = array_dot[j].position.y
            for i in 0...6
            {
                preveri_pozicija = array_dot[j].position.y - 60
                if(preveri_pozicija < 156)
                {
                    break
                }
                print(array_dot[j].name,i,preveri_pozicija,array_dot[j].position.y)


                let novi_node = self.nodeAtPoint(CGPoint(x: array_dot[j].position.x, y: preveri_pozicija))

                if(array_dot[j].intersectsNode(novi_node))
                {
                    array_dot[j].position.y = preveri_pozicija
                    premakni_do = premakni_do - 60
                    print("PRAZNO")
                }
                else
                {
                    break
                }

            }
            array_dot[j].runAction(SKAction.moveToY(premakni_do, duration: 0.2))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure runAction is not working? It may be that you are setting the nodes position and then telling it to move to that position. Try removing the lines

```
            if(array_dot[j].intersectsNode(novi_node))
            {
                array_dot[j].position.y = preveri_pozicija
                premakni_do = premakni_do - 60
                print("PRAZNO")
            }
            else
            {
                break
            }
```

Comment: that does fix the animation issue but now another one arises, the dots above the ones don't move down. i removed the part:
    array_dot[j].position.y = preveri_pozicija